# Generating same GlassMapper model classes without using TDS

Tags: glass-mapper, unicorn

In our project, we are using TDS to sync and serialize Sitecore items. We are also using TDS to generate GlassMapper model classes for all Sitecore Templates. But now, we are planning to use Unicorn to serialize Sitecore Items and use those `.yml` files to generate the GlassMapper model classes.

To do this, we are following https://github.com/hermanussen/sitecore.codegenerator, to generate model interfaces and classes.

Now, the issue is, we want to generate exact same GlassMapper classes what TDS is generating. So that there is minimum changes to the implementation.

One way is to copy all .tt files from TDS and make changes accordingly, as TDS types and utilities will not be available to generate exact same models.

Is there any other simple way to generate exact same model classes and interfaces?

Edit 1:
This question is related to the question mentioned [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/904/using-unicorn-to-generate-glass-mapper-models), as i following the same tool describe in the link but my business need is to generate same GlassMApper model what **TDS** is generating using mentioned approach in the provided link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Unicorn to Generate Glass Mapper Models](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/904/using-unicorn-to-generate-glass-mapper-models)

Comment: No. Its not duplicate. Even i am following the same approach to henerate models  but want exact same or almost equal output, what TDS is giving.